# Expect one or no result from a doctrine query builder, what should I use?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this method:

```
public function getMonth ($month_name)
    {
        $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');

        $q->select('m')
            ->where('m.name = :name')    
            ->setParameter('name', $month_name);

        return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

From it I expect to find one month or 0 months. I use this method in this way in my Controllers:

```
$month = $em->getRepository('EMExpensesBundle:Month')
                ->getMonth($this->findMonth());

            $month->setSpended($item->getPrice());
```

I tried this with `getSingleResult()` and everything was perfect untill I came across a case when no month was found and everything failed really bad!

Then I tried with `getResult()`, but it returns an array and then

```
$month->setSpended($item->getPrice());
```

is said to be called on a non-object and to fix it I should use everywhere

```
$month[0]->setSpended($item->getPrice());
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this without the need to add unnecesary [0] index everywhere?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you use `getSingleResult`, Doctrine throws a `\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException`, which you can catch and handle it. If you want to catch this directly in the Repository, I would suggest:

```
public function getMonth ($month_name)
{
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');

    $q->select('m')
        ->where('m.name = :name')    
        ->setParameter('name', $month_name);

    try {
        return $q->getQuery()->getResult(); 
        }
    catch(\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return new Month();
    }
}
```

Dont forget to add a `use Your\Namespace\Month;` or this will fail because it cannot find the Month class!

Of course you must also persist the Entity in case it is a new one. You could extend the catch block to look like this:

```
catch(\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
    $month = new Month();
    $this->_em->persist($month);

    return $month;
}
```

You could also catch the exception in your controller, making it more transparent. But this depends on your use cases and is best solved by yourself

Answer (score 67):

Additionally, in Doctrine 2.1 you can use 'getOneOrNullResult'

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats

Comment: Better than doing try...catch in repository. Should be the answer to question!

Comment: Be careful, if there is more than one result it just returns an exception.. Not a null value. https://coderwall.com/p/prbrlw/doctrine-get-single-row-or-null : no result: return null // more than one result: throw a NonUniqueResultException exception